# Wait/Notify throw "Failed to decrypt data" in Nifi

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi

I had a simple Wait Notify set up in my Nifi installation. It was working at some point and the only thing that has changed was some certificates in truststore.

Now the following error is thrown in NIFI:[image: Error stack trace]

And I cant figure out what the issue is. Everything else works in terms of SSL communications.

In the wait and Notify Processor, we have the standard DistributedCacheService with the standard SSLContext service.

The version im using is 1.8.0 for Nifi